# Error while reading csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I tried to run following programme in ubuntu terminal but I am getting some error. But it is not giving any error in jupyter notebook

File "imsl.py", line 5
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file imsl.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot


data_file ​= open("mnist_train_100.csv",'r') 
data_list ​=  ​data_file.readlines() 
data_file.close()
```

Comment: this is not the same code that you got an error in, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a stray byte floating around. You can find it by running

```
with open("imsl.py") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if "\xe2" in line:
            print i, repr(line)
```

You'll see the line number and the offending line(s). You can then delete the line and recreate it to remove the stray byte.

You could also add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of the file to enforce encoding, as per your link.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built in `csv` library:

```
import csv

data_file = list(csv.reader(open('mnist_train_100.csv')))
```

Comment: The built in csv library can only handle ASCII, you can try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.0 if you need a unicode CSV reader.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray Unicode byte in the places where `?` is in this code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot


data_file ?= open("mnist_train_100.csv",'r') 
data_list ?=  ?data_file.readlines() 
data_file.close()
```

Correct it, and you're good to go.